# Assets not being found on multiple Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

I have a VPS with two Rails apps being served via Phusion Passenger / NGINX. The setup for this was taken from the [Passenger documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) for setting up apps on a sub-URI.
I can access both pages without a problem. However, I am having a problem with both apps' assets.

The first app, which lives in

```
http://localhost
```

uses the Fontawesome gem. The Fontawesome icons are not displaying at all and I am getting no errors in the Firebug console so it's really hard to debug.

The second, which lives in

```
http://localhost/app2
```

Fontawesome gems *are working* in this second app. However, I am also using some images which I've placed in `/app/assets/images/`. They display properly in development but are nowhere to be seen in production (NetworkError: 404 Not Found).

I know the asset pipeline is tricky but I really can't figure out if it's the asset pipeline doing something funky or if it's my setup that is misplacing the assets?

Thanks

Comment: Have you precompiled?

Comment: Yep, I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clobber && RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean && RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile && touch ./tmp/restart.txt` to restart nginx.

Comment: Checkout your `config/application.rb`. It has some significant Asset Pipeline settings. Try to add this line `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/` and re-run precompilation.

Comment: I solved problem number 2: Fixed by adding `config.relative_url_root = "/app2"` to /config/environments/production.rb
Now to solve Fontawesome not working in app1